# AChartEngine - read y values by x

Tags: android, time-series, achartengine, linechart

I'm currently working on my first android application and now use the achartengine library.

My question: Is there a function to read out y-values from a chart by passing an x-value as a parameter?

I have a line chart using a TimeSeries with several custom dates (for example 07/24/12 and 07/29/12). Now I want to pass another date (for example 07/25/12) and get the corresponding y-value - even though it is not stored in the TimeSeries.

I just wanted to ask, if there is a simple way like a single function to achieve this aim, otherwise I'll think about a more complicated solution on my own. In my above example, of course, it sounds quite easy to calculate the demanded y-value, but in practice it is going to be more difficult I guess.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such thing in AChartEngine.